# Still have problems with the key of backspace in vim of Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, vim

When I first started, I cannot use backspace to delete chars just like in windows. Then I found a solution that to modify the config file (`/etc/vim/vimrc` & `vimrc.tiny`).

This solution enables me to use the backspace to delete the chars I typed in the current file. But I still can not delete the original chars. (Original chars means the content that already exists in the file before I open it.)

E.g.,
there is file named 1.txt, its content:

> abc

Then I open it, typing in three new chars: `def`, the content in this file is:

> abcdef

When I use backspace to delete these chars.

I can delete  `def`, but when the cursor comes to the char `c`, or `b`, or `a`.

It just does not work.

Any help from you will be highly appreciated.

Comment: And what was your solution involving the config files?

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the `'backspace'` option. Put the following in your `~/.vimrc`:

```
set backspace=indent,eol,start
```

You also should also be using `~/.vimrc` instead of `/etc/vim/vimrc`.

Please take a look at the following:

```
:h 'backspace'
:h vimrc-intro
:h vimrc_example.vim
```

Comment: Really appreciate your response. But I can find the file "~/.vimrc". And I was confused by "using ~/.vimrc instead of /etc/vim/vimrc"? How?

Comment: `~/.vimrc` is where your *personal* `.vimrc` resides on a unix like platform. `/etc/vim/vimrc` is the system's vimrc which will be used as the default for any user w/o their own vimrc. This file maybe be overridden when upgrading vim. You can edit your vimrc by doing the following `:e $MYVIMRC`. For more vimrc information see: `:h vimrc`

Comment: Really thanks. There is no .vimrc file under my home directory. Just add it.